# Return values in column that only occur once

Tags: r

This seems like something very basic, but unique and distinct functions dont work in this case.

```
a <- as_tibble(c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5))
a
# A tibble: 8 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     4
7     4
8     5
```

The result should be a tibble, where i only have values, that dont appear more than one time, like this:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1     3
2     5
```

I tried unique and distinct, but that ofcourse gives me:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

which is not what i want.

Comment: `a %>% group_by(value) %>% filter(n() == 1)`

Comment: Thanks! Why do you choose a comment instead of an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, this is indeed a bit ugly. :) Notice that example you provided differs from the printed text.

```
xy <- data.frame(value = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5))

un <- table(xy$value)
un <- un[un == 1]
xy[xy$value %in% names(un), , drop = FALSE]

  value
5     3
8     5
```

Comment: you are right, i fixed it. and man, how much experience does one need to figure that out?!

Comment: You could have used `which(un==1)`

Comment: @GeorgeSavva feel free to modify my answer.